# CakePHP Redirect method not working?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, redirect

We started following the CakePHP Blog tutorial hosted on the website cakephp.org - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

At this point we're stuck on the redirecting after submitting a form (i.e. function edit / add). This is how our code looks like:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;

    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Post->read();
    } else {
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated.');
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update your post.');
        }
    }
}
```

After commenting the line `$this->redirect($this->referer());` the page is refering to his own... with the line added it'll stay on a empty white page.

Example: http://www.drukwerkprijsvergelijk.nl/posts/

Please help this little kittens, we're desperate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot use referer() on edit. thats because after the first POST the referer is the same page as you are on right now.
referer() can only be used for redirects if there was no form post on this page (delete for example or edit/add right after accessing the page).
but even with delete() you must be careful. coming from "view" would result the redirect to run into a redirect loop...

you can store the referer in the form as hidden field and use this to redirect back.

Comment: It's also not working on my add() method. 

I.e. $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); is also not working.

Comment: if there is NO redirect at all you probably echo sth too soon (in the php part - bootstrap/controller/model/..) and therefore headers are already sent and your redirect cannot work anymore. make sure all php files do not have closing ?> and you don't output anything at all prior to the redirect.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I did several ?> endings, I will not fail sir!

Comment: did it work out? have you found the source of the redirect problem?

Comment: Yes, the ?> was the problem ;)!

Comment: Hello, I know this is an old post but i just wanted to ask something.
I have it working now when i removed the "?>", but in another project i is working fine with the closing "?>"; so do you know what is the reason for that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the reasons mark explained above, you can't use referer() on edit and add.

Use something like

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $id));
```

or

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

instead.

You can also try specifying the controller in the url array:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any whitespace outside the PHP code in your PostController or your AppController ? I just looked at the source code of your edit page and it seems to contain a space character. This could prevent the headers to be set, thus preventing the redirect to work.

Comment: All obove answer were obvious to check first , this was totally helpfull after searching my page for 5 hours for syntex errors

Answer (score 1):

Use this one in before filter function

```
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); // // HTTP/1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
```